# I'm looking for a personal/small-team knowledge manager, alternatives to wikis

Tags: web-apps, knowledge-base, knowledge-organization

I'm looking for a [personal knowledge manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_knowledge_base), that can be used by multiple people with different accounts.

It should be web-based and free and preferably open-source. Situation is as follows, I do something, it might be hard it might be easy, I want to write it down. Normally, I'd use plain paper, but it's really easy to lose track of everything I write down, so I prefer a digital solution.

I've looked at wikis, but I'm not a great fan of them, in the way that they are structured. They are structured as linked bits of information, instead, when I'm working on a project, the information has a very clear relation, day one, I do this, day two, I do that, while a wiki is great at sharing information, it's not good at sharing a roadmap of where you started, and where you ended up.

The advantage of such a system is that you can easily share it with someone, and without an explanation, they can end up where I ended up.

Preferably, such software should be free, open-source and self hostable, we don't live in a perfect world though, so I'm not sure if there is such a thing. As for technical requirements, I should be able to write text, use a markup language (Markdown, BBCode, HTML, anything) or a WYSIWYG editor, I prefer the luxury of both.

Comment: http://www.capterra.com/knowledge-management-software ?

Comment: Please provide more information.  What don't you like about wikis? Can you host it yourself, or does it need to be an existing web platform? What kind of documentation do you intend on putting in it? What other features do you need (file uploads, formatting, etc)?  See [the guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) for more things to consider adding.

Comment: @Bobson I've added an explanation.

Comment: Second time today recommending foswiki. Check it, and you will see than it is totally different beast when comparing it with mediawiki, or docuwiki and such. It has zilion macros, what allows you attach data to topices, attach documents, full text search, creating wiki-apllications (using macros) and many other cool things.

Comment: [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/) includes a simple editor for ODT files (open document text, the format used e.g. by OpenOffice/LibreOffice), and versioning (amongst other features). You can share resources (e.g. single files or entire directories) amongst users, so collaboration is possible. Would that be an option? Might be the "roadmap" feature is not exactly met (maybe you [edit] your question again and elaborate a little on what you have in mind concerning that).

Comment: @Azeirah - Thank you.  *Much* clearer what you’re looking for now.  I don’t currently use anything that matches that description, but it sounds familiar… I’m sure I’ve seen something like it.  I’ll try to remember what it was.

Comment: Could you describe the workflow you desire? For example, how should it work to add a note for day 3? Do you have a single page with all days and add a section? Do you have separate pages structured under a specific project? Do you have a diary? etc.

Comment: I don't know if this fits the bill but it is clearly project management software.  http://www.projectlibre.org/